# jsoup search div with wild card?

Tags: html, jsoup, wildcard, contains

e- Hi
I would like to find divs that could be named `<div class=class-A...` or `<div class=class-B...`

How could I search somthing like class-* ? I tried select with :contains with no success but not sure of the correct syntax I should use.

Thanks,

Olivier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [css selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html):

```
Elements divs = document.select("div[class^=class-]");
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use CSS selector in this case, e.g.:

`div[class*="class-"]` which means `div` with `class` that contains `class-`

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Advanced_CSS_selectors#Attribute_selectors

Comment: Thanks, it works but without the ' character. I understood that in this case, it's not only the start but the string can be anywhere.